# Why are my generated MIDI notes so spaced? - Remove empty gap from beginning and end of midi files

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, midi

I followed the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/music_generation and tried to apply the same idea to YM2413-MDB-v1.0.2. However, I noticed that in some cases, the notes are really far apart, resulting in a single note playing at a time, which sounds really boring and off.

I think this has to do with some MIDI files having large areas of no notes playing. I am unsure how to avoid this because on one hand gaps in music have meaning, on the other I think that especially longer gaps at the end or beginning should be easy to filter. I am not that familiar with machine learning or MIDI, so I am looking for some guidance.